# Ruby 'module_function' vs. including module

Tags: ruby, module, mixins

In Ruby, I understand that module functions can be made available without mixing in the module by using `module_function` as shown here. I can see how this is useful so you can use the function without mixing in the module.

```
module MyModule
  def do_something
    puts "Hello, World!"
  end
  module_function :do_something
end
```

Why might you want to have the function defined both of these ways?

Why not just have

```
def MyModule.do_something
```

OR

```
def do_something
```

In what kind of cases would it be useful to have the function available to be mixed in, or to be used as a static method?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Think of [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html).

This is the perfect example of when you need to include it in a module. If your class defines `#each`, you get a lot of goodness just by including a module (`#map`, `#select`, etc.). This is the only case when I use modules as mixins - when the module provides functionality in terms of a few methods, defined in the class you include the module it. I can argue that this should be the only case in general.

As for defining "static" methods, a better approach would be:

```
module MyModule
  def self.do_something
  end
end
```

You don't really need to call `#module_function`. I think it is just weird legacy stuff.

You can even do this:

```
module MyModule
  extend self

  def do_something
  end
end
```

...but it won't work well if you also want to include the module somewhere. I suggest avoiding it until you learn the subtleties of the Ruby metaprogramming.

Finally, if you just do:

```
def do_something
end
```

...it will not end up as a global function, but as a private method on `Object` (there are no functions in Ruby, just methods). There are two downsides. First, you don't have namespacing - if you define another function with the same name, it's the one that gets evaluated later that you get. Second, if you have functionality implemented in terms of `#method_missing`, having a private method in `Object` will shadow it. And finally, monkey patching `Object` is just evil business :)

EDIT:

`module_function` can be used in a way similar to `private`:

```
module Something
  def foo
    puts 'foo'
  end

  module_function

  def bar
    puts 'bar'
  end
end
```

That way, you can call `Something.bar`, but not not `Something.foo`. If you define any other methods after this call to `module_function`, they would also be available without mixing in.

I don't like it for two reasons, though. First, modules that are both mixed in and have "static" methods sound a bit dodgy. There might be valid cases, but it won't be that often. As I said, I prefer either to use a module as a namespace or mix it in, but not both.

Second, in this example, `bar` would also be available to classes/modules that mix in `Something`. I'm not sure when this is desirable, since either the method uses `self` and it has to be mixed in, or doesn't and then it does not need to be mixed in.

I think using `module_function` without passing the name of the method is used quite more often than with. Same goes for `private` and `protected`.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I understand why you would want to mix in a module, my question was more about when you might actually use the module_function. Is there any time you might actually use it?

Comment: There's one more catch in this last example with `module_function`: The "private" function `foo` cannot be accessed from inside `bar`, because `foo` is then an instance method (it doesn't have `self`), and it can be called only when this module is mixed in some class. Impossible when it is a stand-alone module just for namespacing purposes. So how to have it both? How to use module just for namespacing and hide some implementation helper functions from the outside world, but allow them to be called by its interface methods?

Answer (score 16):

It's a good way for a Ruby library to offer functionality that does not use (much) internal state. So if you (e.g.) want to offer a `sin` function and don't want to pollute the "global" (`Object`) namespace, you can define it as class method under a constant (`Math`).

However, an app developer, who wants to write a mathematical application, might need `sin` every two lines. If the method is also an instance method, she can just include the `Math` (or `My::Awesome::Nested::Library`) module and can now directly call `sin` (stdlib example).

It's really about making a library more comfortable for its users. They can choose themself, if they want the functionality of your library on the top level.

By the way, you can achieve a similar functionality like `module_function` by using: `extend self` (in the first line of the module). To my mind, it looks better and makes things a bit clearer to understand.

**Update:** More background info in [this blog article](http://idiosyncratic-ruby.com/8-self-improvement.html).

Comment: The [ruby styleguide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#classes--modules) prefers ``module_function`` over ``extend self``

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I disagree with it, though. `module_function` might be friendlier to beginners, but everyone who is doing serious Ruby should be able to read and understand the `extend self` version. `extend self` is less abstraction. It uses Ruby's base toolset, while `module_function` could be removed from Ruby, without losing important functionality.

Comment: Thank you for giving your reasons. Before reading this Q/A, I was using ``self.method`` and ``class << self``.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to look at a working example, check out [handlers.rb](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic/blob/master/lib/chronic/handlers.rb) in the [Chronic](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic/tree/master) gem.

And Handlers is being included in the Parser class in [parser.rb](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic/blob/master/lib/chronic/parser.rb).

It's using *module_function* to send the methods from Handlers to specific instances of Handler using that instance's invoke method.